# AngularJS 1.3 - why is the form valid on load, for inputs with a minimum length?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just getting started with AngularJS and wish to disable the submit button of the form, if the form has **any** fields which are invalid.

I have a field called Title. It has a requirement that the *minlength* is 5. On load of the form, the form object provided by AngularJS reports that `$invalid: false`

```
<div ng-controller="NewPinCtrl as newPin">

<form role="form" name="formNewPin">

    <div>
        <label>Title</label>
        <input ng-model="newPin.pin.title" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="140" type="text" name="title" value="" placeholder="Title" />
        <ul ng-messages="formNewPin.title.$error" ng-if="formNewPin.title.$dirty">
            <li ng-message="required">This is required</li>
            <li ng-message="minlength">Should be longer than 5 characters</li>
            <li ng-message="maxlength">Should be shorter than 140 characters</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</form>

</div>
```

And here is my button:

```
<button ng-click="newPin.savePin()" ng-disabled="formNewPin.$pristine || formNewPin.$invalid" type="button">Submit</button>
```

Fine I thought, I'll just disable the button if the form is `$pristine: true`. That solved my 'on load' issue...but when a user clears the field and goes back to blank, `$invalid` reports as `false`.

Why is this, when the field clearly has a minlength requirement? And, how can I get around it without checking each form field error individually?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I might add, that I'm using this new ngMessages for 1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have provided the message for required error, but you haven't marked the input as required. That's why it is evaluated as valid on first load.

After adding required attribute, you won't need using ng-if for ng-messages. The final solution should look like this:

```
<form name="formNewPin">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input ng-model="newPin.pin.title" required ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="140" type="text" name="title" value="" placeholder="Title">

    <ul ng-messages="formNewPin.title.$error">
        <li ng-message="required">This is required</li>
        <li ng-message="minlength">Should be longer than 5 characters</li>
        <li ng-message="maxlength">Should be shorter than 140 characters</li>
    </ul>
  <button ng-click="newPin.savePin()" ng-disabled="formNewPin.$invalid" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vl56kuEOFYxaRxVRlWLG?p=preview) for this.

Comment: You are correct! Thank you so much - what an oversight on my part. I also had to add the novalidate attribute on my form to prevent default HTML5 browser validation. Now working as expected.